# Is there a way to bypass the ruby redis wrapper and direct a command to redis?

Tags: ruby, redis

I want to use the incrbyfloat command that exists in the unstable version of redis, but the redis-rb wrapper doesn't include a method call for this.  Is there a way to make a call directly to redis within redis-rb (I can't find a way to do this), or should I just fork redis-rb and add that method myself?

Answer (score 1):

Just discovered that redis-rb has a method_missing method which will pass unknown redis commands... doh!